# Is DNS required to register gitlab runner?

Tags: dns, gitlab, x509certificate, gitlab-ci-runner, runner

When i register a runner with  https://34.66.66.103/gitlab/ as url , it throws the below error. but when i add a dns to it. it works fine!. I'm just wondering is DNS really required for runner registration?
Can't runners be registered to gitlab with an elb ?

```
    ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=zMXQGYf_ status=couldn't execute POST against https://34.66.66.103/gitlab/api/v4/runners: Post https://34.66.66.103/gitlab/api/v4/runners: x509: cannot validate certificate for 34.66.66.103 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
    PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

Comment: The certificate needs to have the IP address in the SAN section if you have HTTPS links with IP addresses in them, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

As @`Patrick Mevzek` pointed out in the comments, your error seems to be an issue with the IP config, not with Gitlab Runners.

The end of your error message states:
`cannot validate certificate for 34.66.66.103 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs`

Either try adding IP SANs to your IP, or try to use DNS.

Looks like someone here had a similar issue: https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1654